# angular-translate issue when interpolating parameters with escapeParameters sanitization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sanitization, angular-translate

I'm encountering a weird issue (no translation displayed) when using angular-translate, with parameters interpolation as date objects.

But first things first: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8NevDFkRuPsu8ZlTLO6l?p=preview)'s the plunker.

.

Using a sanitization strategy 'escapeParameters' in the translate provider,

why with a json formatted like this:

```
$scope.title = { day: 'tomorrow', today: new Date() };
```

the results of my translations are always {}, using the contracted forms

```
{{'VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT' | translate : title}}

<translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{ day: 'tomorrow', today: title.today }">
```

As you can see, the other ways of using angular-translate seems to work fine. Is this some kind of bug? Or i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone wondering, i opened a issue on github repository of angular-translate: this problem will be fixed in 2.11.2 (next version of the current release).
More on the issue [here](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1560).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known bug. At https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security they say

> Currently there is an issue with the sanitize mode, it will double
>   encode UTF-8 characters or special characters. Recommendation: use the
>   'escape' [instead of 'escapeParameters'] strategy, until this is
>   resolved.

So, I guess if you want to use the variations in your first and third tests, you might have to stick with the 'escape' strategy. Or alternatively, format your date string to not have whichever character is causing the problem.

When I edited your plunker to use 'escape', all four of your tests worked fine.

Comment: Sadly, i need to disagree: using 'escape' sanitization strategy does not seems to work fine with special characters i need, like the '>' in the example (you can see it's resolved in &gt). So the solution of using escape is not acceptable for me. +1 for the effort though.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. I was just looking at the date values, which did appear when changing the strategy.